# identify data.frames in list that contain duplicates in any of multiple columns and print their location in `stop`

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have a list `ls` of two data.frames. I want to check `if` there are any duplicates in two or multiple columns in each data.frame and print the matching data.frame and columns.  What is a more efficient way to write this? Also, how do I include `test` inside `stop`, so that it prints as a data.frame?

```
ls <- list(a = iris, b = iris)

test <- ls %>%
  map_df( ~ map_lgl(
    list(
      Petal.Length = .$Petal.Length,
      Petal.Width = .$Petal.Width
    ),
    ~ any(duplicated(.))
  )) 

if (any(test)) {
  stop("Contains duplicates: ", 
        print.data.frame(test %>% 
           bind_cols(ls = names(ls), .)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does most of what you want

```
library(tidyverse)

ls <- list(a=data.frame(x=1:9),
           b=head(iris),
           c=head(mtcars))

pipefilt <- function(x,f){Filter(f =\(x){nrow(x)>0},x)}

evaluation <- map(ls,
    ~{df_ <- .x
      map(df_,
        ~{
          which(duplicated(.x))
        
         })|> enframe() |> rowwise() |> filter(!identical(value,integer(0)))
    }) |> pipefilt()
  

if(length(evaluation)>0){
  eval_print <- paste0(capture.output(print(evaluation)),collapse="\n")
  stop(paste0("contains duplicates:\n\n",eval_print))
}
```